# elastic search search index for keywords phrases or keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search and have an index with lots of articles in it. I have 3 main fields I use;  title, snippet and date. I want to find the most common or top key-phrases or keywords for a specific date in the title field. I was hoping someone can provide an example on how to do this or at least point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Try something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "date": {
        "query": "your_date"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "common_words": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will find common words at the top as they are ordered by count.
If you are looking for `phrases` you might have to `analyze` your title field accordingly. You can map title with [multiple analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html). for e.g `standard analyzer` for common words and [shingle analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) for common phrases.

You also might want to look into [significant terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html) if you want to find something unusual.

Comment: I think I'll mark this as the answer. I was playing with the sample you gave me for the last day and I find the significant terms yields some good results. But, it seems the more I play around the more questions I have, I'll save those for another post if I get stuck. Thank you  ChintanShah25.

Comment: I am glad I could help, significant terms is bit tricky, [This](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2015/06/10/how-elasticsearch-calculates-significant-terms/) is a good read. This is the [video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/elasticsearch-revealing-uncommonly-common) by author. Also do not hesitate to ask more questions. It would be good if you could provide mapping and some sample documents next time so that we can help you better. :)